# Why is 1 John 5:7 a trinitarian verse?

Tags: 1-john, trinity, attributes-of-god

First up, this is not about whether the verse is an addition or not. Let's assume for a moment it is not and has sufficient authenticity to remain.

> For there are three that bear record in heaven, the Father, the Word, and the Holy Ghost: and these three are one. KJV

I notice that the verse omits the 'Son'. There is then ample biblical support for the word, the spirit and the Father to be **One God**!

This is an even better verse for NON-trinitarian believers, as it makes no claim for the son being part of this ONE GOD. (If required this support can be provided, but could be part of an answer)

Is there reason to *assume* (based on the immediate context) this is meant to convey a trinitarian dogma? Or was something else intended?

Comment: word=son. Question is looking   more of a systematic theological trinity question which are very bad for this site. Christianity SE will be better for it.

Comment: Word only =son in T theology. It is not a biblical reality. Hence the question and why it should be on this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the text of scripture but asks why a certain verse is labelled in a certain way.

Comment: Many Trinitarians reject the influence that was placed on Erasmus in order to include what is essentially Latin-based wording. Many Trinitarians reject the idea of including _logos_ alongside 'Father'. It is clearly not in accord with other scripture. That is why the Johannine Comma is rejected by many Trinitarians on textual/manuscript grounds.

Comment: It is taken as Trinitarian because "The Word" is one of the titles of Jesus on the Basis of John 1:1, 14, Rev 19:13.

Comment: One of the reasons we do not explore Bible verse questions directed explicitly toward understanding them through the lens of the doctrine of the Trinity is that the Trinity is not a hermeneutically-derived theology; the Trinity is a compiled response to the Aseans and Arians in the first four ecumenical councils intended to refute heresy. Whether verses supporting the decisions of those councils answer questions of the Oneness movement is not something those councils addressed. The Bible could go either way so long as claiming Jesus is neither angel nor creation, but that is a matter for C.SE.

Comment: Whenever we break our standards and cross that line, we tend to see [viewpoint swarming](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4013/27581) in the comments, which we can't have.

Comment: @Jesse - I have questions/concerns here: 1) It usually takes 5 votes to close a Q and yet this was closed after 4 votes. 2) Q's, and even comments, *in support* of the Trinity are nearly always allowed, but not so when the other way around, as I myself know all too well, especially recently. 3) I see that this long time poster had *already* been "temporarily suspended" for rules violations, and yet here he is posting before his suspension is due to end. Regarding "close" votes, It seems to usually be the same few individuals (trinitarians) who wish to silence/attack differing viewpoints .. tbc

Comment: @Jesse - It's a shame that a few users do this, because when the site is working as I think it should, it can be a very positive opportunity for learning from a variety of perspectives, and I would think/hope that it could encourage people that disagree on many topics to find and appreciate the common ground that they might have.

Comment: @OldeEnglish I'm going to share this with the other mods so they can pipe in, just to keep objective. 1) When a mod votes to act on a post, it happens instantly; I voted without much waiting since three already had, so it wasn't fringe, and it supported them. 2) Not really. I am quite sympathetic to Oneness, actually. It's purely an issue of topic and voiding comment swarms, like this could be. I invite you to share examples on a meta.BH, though I'm not sure "Trinity" is the overt aim, which would be why they are allowed. I don't silence theo, but swarming. 3) Yes, strange indeed.

Comment: @OldeEnglish It can indeed be positive, and many perspectives are welcome. But, making the perspective the purpose of a post—regardless of the position—is what makes it ugly. We mods try to prevent the viewpoint swarming, not the specific opinions, and keep focused on Bible interpretation *process*.

Comment: @Jesse - I forgot to mention. The poster's (suspended or no) question is not even on the "Home" page anymore, whereas "Closed" questions usually stay on, even when closed, and are just marked closed. My answer should, IMO, still at least be still viewable. Don't you think? It seems that I get the short end of the stick all too often. I often wonder why I even bother.

Comment: @OldeEnglish Good questions. Time for another mod to step in and help answer. Both the question and your answer are visible even when logged out. The matter of the user is being looked at and is in good hands.

Comment: @OldeEnglish on 3) the user posted this via a second account, which has now been merged into his primary. 1) there's a long standing issue with lack of engagement with the voting queues - this has improved a bit recently but often we do need to step in and Close clearly Off Topic Questions fast enough to stop them proliferating. when more people help in the queues we don't need to intervene as often. 4 votes seems perfectly reasonable. 2) I think we'd aim to be impartial on all these things. I delete plenty of trinitarian comments every week, but it's difficult to be sure of the balance.

Comment: We've got a Meta post in the works that will more clearly lay out how Comments should/n't be used. We're trying to improve this across the site in line with other SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

**Why is 1 John 5:7 a trinitarian verse?**

Faith in Jesus Christ as the savior of mankind , through his "Ransom Sacrifice", is what's at stake for earthly man here. What is not at stake is mankind's belief in a *triune* God. Consequently, I am of the opinion that the verse's authenticity, to remain, is questionable. What we would seem to have here is a *possible* case of -trinitarian leaning - translators bias, taking advantage of the 3 in 1 (in agreement) concept, in order to convey their trinitarian dogma.

If we take verses 5 through 8, apart from verse 7, **who** and **what** are we talking about after all. We are talking about Jesus Christ, with regard to the **"who"**. With regard to the **"what"**, we are talking about Jesus' (in agreement) witness bearers, the three:- noun-nominative *neuter* singulars, i.e. the *spirit* and the *water* and the *blood*. Consequently, we have the truth (*spirit*); the baptism (*water*); and the blood (*ransom sacrifice*), period. All the *earthly* attributes, with regard to the **Son of Man**. Attributes, for *earthly* man to consider and understand, as having been manifested out/by way of, the Son of God, through faith in - all that is encompassed by - the "Ransom Sacrifice".

Answer (score 2):

> "This is he that came by water and blood, even Jesus Christ; not by
> water only but by water and blood. And it is the Spirit that beareth
> witness, because the Spirit is truth. For there are three that bear
> record in heaven, the Father, the Word and the Holy Ghost: and these
> three are one." Verses 6 and 7 KJV
>
> "For there are three that testify in heaven: the Father, the Word and
> the Holy Spirit, and these three are one. And there are three that
> testify on earth, the....  are in agreement." Latin Vulgate

There are Latin MSS from the 6th century A.D. that DO contain the trinity of Father, Son and Holy Spirit. Protestant apologist Bruce Metzger agrees and says in, *"A Textual Commentary of the Greek N.T"* (1975, pp 716-718) that the phrase is first found in the treatise, ***‘Liber Apologeticus’ of the 4th century and in Old Latin & Vulgate Bible manuscripts beginning in the 6th century.***

***John Gill's commentary on 1 John 5:7 says this is referred to by Tertullian about the year 200*** -

> "The text is found in 8 extant Greek manuscripts and 5 of them dated
> before the 16th century. [Greek miniscules  88, 221, 429, 629 & 636].
> There are at least 8,000 extant Latin MSS and many of them contain 1
> John 5:7, the really important ones being the Old Latin which Church
> Fathers, such as Tertullian (A.D. 155-220) and Cyprian (200-258)
> used."

Those ancient sources are interesting, and **substantiate your comment** that those [two] verses have ***"sufficient authenticity to remain."*** However, I included verse 6 at the start because that does, indeed, identify Jesus Christ as one of the "three" mentioned in verse 7. With verse 7 starting with, "For...", it is impossible to ignore what the 'for' referred to in the preceding verse is - where Jesus Christ is clearly identified. And most of us know that in John 1:1-14 the Word became flesh, and was identified as Jesus Christ.

Finally, you ask if the verse[s] "*convey a trinitarian dogma? Or was something else intended?*" The Latin word 'trinity' had not been coined at the time those verses were written, so a simple answer would be, "No - this (in itself) is not a dogma". However, as to what would, then, be intended, that is a matter of interpretation. Those who object to the Trinity doctrine will say something else was intended, while those who see in those verses support for trinitarian thinking would not look for a different intention. This will never be resolved to the satisfaction of those who are convinced there is no trinitarian basis in scripture for the Trinity doctrine. So, I will leave my answer at that, even if you are not satisfied by it.

Comment: The comments of Barnes, rather than Gill, I find very interesting. Barnes thought 5:7 to be *spurious* and went into great length in his reasonings as to why.